# Does Delphi support to add string with different languages to resource?

Tags: string, delphi, localization, resources

The string table in resource of EXE or DLL actually support multiple languages. Therefore, in Delphi, is there a built-in way to add string to resource and specify the language for it at the same time. Also is there a built-in way to retrieve the string with a specific language?

Currently resourcestring can add string to resource, but without a language.

By adding a laugage to the project, there will be a separate language resource file, not a resource in the current project.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know Delphi does not support accessing resources intended for specific language if they are all stored in same resource file. Instead it relies on compiling multiple resource libraries (DLL's) that you ship alongside the executable of your application. The main disadvantage of this is that you no longer have ability to ship just one single file to your users. But one of the big advantages of this is that upon application start only resources for used language are loaded into memory. ...

Comment: ... If you would have resources for multiple languages stored in same resource file all of them would have to be loaded into memory upon start of your application. Now imagine that your application has thousands of strings, texts and language specific images which take about 1 MB of memory and then you go and translate this to about 100 different languages. Now your application would use 100+ MB of memory just for all those string, texts, etc. But if you have language based resources stored in separate file then you can only load those resources that you actually need for specific language